# C++ Vector of linked lists

Tags: c++

I have a nested template argument in the form of

`vector<list<int, string> >`.

That is, it's a vector of linked lists that hold integer values and string words. If this is not a valid form, please let me know. My question is in calling it. If 'table' is of the above data type, would it be okay to call an index as, for example, table[0]? If so, how do I start walking through the linked list in that index?

Comment: How do you start walking a linked list if its *not* in a vector? Do that, but for the linked list at `table[n]`. Also note: your `list<int,string>` isn't valid. there is no such type for `std::list`, assuming that is what you're using. I think you mean `std::vector<std::list<std::string>>`

Comment: table[0] will be just your first list, and then you walk through it as you would do through any other list. Though you probably meant `list< pair <int,string> >`

Comment: Please post example code of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

With the nested data structure you've defined, you are exactly correct to call an index like you mentioned, `table[0]`. You can perform your list operations on that exactly. To make your code more clean, it can be helpful to do something like:

```
list<string> listInVector = table[i];
```

So you don't get confused performing operations on an index in `table`, instead you can use that identifier to make the code more clean.

Comment: Given that copying containers tends to be quite expensive, I'd guess you`d really want to use `std::list<std::string>& listInVector = ...` or a `const`-qualified version thereof.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the containers are individual elements. If you want to have multiple elements, e.g., an `int` and a `std::string` you'll need to put them into a suitable structure, e.g., into a `std::pair<int, std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>>> table;
```

To walk the elements in the list at a specific position you could use, e.g.:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, std::strin>>::iterator it(table[i].begin()), end(table[i].end());
for (; it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << "int=" << it->first << " string=" << it->second << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"If this is not a valid form, please let me know"*

Yes its not valid, I think you meant :-

`std::vector< std::list<std::pair<std::string, int> > > table ;`

How to access ?

Something like :-

```
typedef std::pair<std::string , int> ele;
std::list<ele>::iterator it = table[i].begin(); //for ith table

for(;it!=table[i].end();++it)
 std::cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second;
```